# Where to get public domain East Asian book illustrations?

Tags: illustration, resource-recommendations, book, free

There are public domain resources (such as those [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Public_domain_image_resources)) where one can obtain illustrations from old books. However, most of these illustrations are of the "European style" (i.e. European subjects, European buildings, European drawing methods, European scenery, etc.) as they were made in Europe or the Americas.

I have had great difficulty in finding equivalent resources for East Asian illustrations. Are there any public domain resources where one can obtain public domain East Asian book illustrations?

Examples of the "East Asian illustrations" in question:

[image: Japanese Counting Board]

[image: Empty Fort Strategy]

[image: Windy Ride]

Comment: Smithsonian Libraries: [Japanese Illustrated Books from the Edo and Meiji Periods](https://library.si.edu/digital-library/collection/japanese-illustrated-books)

Comment: Have you tried searching with terms translated in one of the Eastern Asian languages?

Answer (score 3):

### By simply searching for ***east asian illustrations "public domain"***

You aren't going to find a magical repository with all the images ever so you'll need to put some legwork in.

With that simple search I found:

- [A collection of Japanese and Chinese prints of the Sino-Japanese War](https://www.jacar.go.jp/english/jacarbl-fsjwar-e/index.html)
- [Illustrations from RawPixel](https://www.rawpixel.com/search/East%20Asian?sort=curated&freecc0=1&page=1)
- [This page of **OVER 20** sites that have free collections](https://sia.libguides.com/images/freeimageresources)
- [BASE which is a search engine that finds material in institutional repositories. Of several such search engines, BASE currently seems to be the one that finds most images](https://www.base-search.net/)
- [Collections on Open Image](https://blogs.ntu.edu.sg/openimagecollections/project_tag/east-asian/)
- [A list of public domain sites from the Library of the University of Toronto](https://guides.library.utoronto.ca/c.php?g=250820&p=1671955)

This is page 1 of a Google search, going deeper in these links and searching would surely yield more results.